# A tool in Xcode to check wether a function retains or not?

Tags: ios, retain, reference-counting, assign

I'm currently working on an iOs application, and there is this one thing that is such a pain in the... well, a pain anyway : I always have to check the documentation to know wether an object property is retained or not (for instance, the setDelegate of the UITextField assigns the delegate and doesn't retain it, whereas the setFont function retains... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html)

It's... a pain. Is there a way to know such a thing directly in Xcode ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Delegates are a special case because what you are setting as a delegate is usually an object which would have a lifetime exceeding or equal to the object it is delegating for (i.e, a view controller would be the delegate of a text field). Because of this design pattern delegates are assigned, not retained, to avoid retain cycles. If you are creating a new object to act as the delegate for some other object, then you would have to retain it, but it doesn't quite smell right to be doing it that way.

For the rest of the cases, I really don't understand what your issue is, or why you are checking the documentation. You don't need to care about the retaining or otherwise that framework objects do to their properties. You only need to care about the retains and releases that you have made in your own code.

Do you have an example of a non-delegate property in a UIKit object that you have to retain yourself because the UIKit object is not retaining it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Objective C. But I think you don't really need to know. You just pass the property and it's up to the class (UITextField in this case) to retain it or not. You don't have to keep it around after passing it unless you need it for something else.

Also, try switching to ARC, a lot less of headaches for beginners.

Comment: I'm not a total beginner, no more headaches for me, I undestand quite well what happens with retain or not. But some function do, some function don't, and it's retarded that you have to check the doc each time... But I like to have control over what happens in the memory, so arc is not for me yet... And we still support iOS 4, so really not for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer: switch to supporting iOS5 only and use ARC. You (mostly) don't need to worry about this kind of thing.

But, really, you don't need such a tool anyway. The conventions are very simple.

- If you alloc, retain or copy something, you need to release it at some point
- Otherwise you don't

Delegates are, in practice, no different. Why? Well, the delegate has to be around at least as long as the object with the delegate. So, unlike your setFont: example, you are very unlikely to do `alloc; delegate = ...; release`.

Comment: Nope. The delegate is not retained, just assigned, and therefor you have to save the ref sometime, and release it at the end, when you don't need the object no more... And we still need to support ios 4, for some more time (not for long, but still). When I say "we", I mean "my company and I"

Comment: Yup. The normal usage pattern is that your view controller creates, say, a UITextField and acts as its delegate. You want to avoid the situation where you send a message to the delegate after it has been deallocated. But since the text field will be deallocated before the view controller that's never going to happen, and you don't need to retain the delegate.

Comment: If you want to add another rule to my list it's: delegates are not retained. This is to avoid retain cycles. Generally -- not always but almost always -- retaining the delegate is a sign that your memory management is incorrect, or at least overly complex.

Comment: Yup, the documentation said that : @property(nonatomic, assign) id<UITextFieldDelegate> delegate. That's why I thought : "hell, if the documentation says such thing, maybe it's available in Xcode somewhere." Therefore my question for a tool :'(